# Why was Luis' van stored under Scott's name at the storage facility?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, ant-man-2015

In the post five-year future of *Avengers: Endgame*, we see Luis' van at a self-storage facility behind a metallic fence with a label named "**LANG**":

[image: The van behind the fence showing the sign]
 <sub>Avengers: Endgame (2019): *click the image to enlarge*</sub>

Considering what we see in *Ant-Man*,

> **Scott Lang**: Hey, how’s your girl, man?
>
> **Luis**: Uh, she left me.
>
> **Scott Lang**: Oh.
>
> **Luis**: Yeah, my mom died too. And my dad got deported. **But I got the van!**
>    <sub>*Ant-Man (2015)*</sub>

It is clear that Luis owns the van. And according to the records, Scott Lang was missing and presumed to be dusted (as his name was found at the memorial at San Francisco).

So why was it stored under Scott's name at the storage facility?

Comment: It might be Cassie's name.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yeah. True. But that still doesn’t tell us why is Luis’ can under Cassie’s name then. TheLethalCarrot’s answer is on point I feel

Comment: @Shreedar: yeah I was thinking maybe she claimed the van and all associated stuff after the snap, and put it in storage. Granted, she was like 8 years old or something at the time, but maybe whatever surviving parents she had put it under her name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the van was likely "sold" to Scott as the founder of X-Con Security Consultants considering it was their property now. You can see the logo for X-Con on the side of the van when Scott goes into the Quantum Tunnel at the end of *Ant-Man and the Wasp* and it's also visible when Scott goes up to Avengers HQ in *Avengers: Endgame* as we see in the security footage

[image: The van on the roof showing the logo] [image: The van at Avengers HQ in the security footage with the logo visible]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

As no one was there to collect the van after the Snap presumably Luis and the rest of the team were also dusted but I can't find any information on this either way. Though again it makes sense else they would have likely let Scott out sooner. As no one was there to claim the van it would have been stored under the registered keeper's name for collection if and when they turned up.

It’s also worth noting, as Valorum mentions in the comments, that post-Snap there would have been thousands of abandoned vehicles that needed clearing up. There may not have been time, or need, to want to find their proper owners and so authorities probably went with whatever documentation they found in the vehicle, for example, a driver’s license.

Comment: The X-con logo on the van. That was the key.